# Spinning wheel in jquery with mouse-drag option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a plugin for spinning wheel in jquery. I came across the site 
http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm  . There is a beautiful demonstration of spinning wheel here but I need the images to be controlled on mouse-drag and also I want the same rotation to happen vertically as well. please help

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is commonly referred to as a 'Developer'. When you come to Stackoverflow (in general) you provide a source code that we look through to find out where your mistake(s) is/are. Then we tell you why the mistake(s) happen/ed, and steer you through correcting the mistake(s). If what you are you looking for is the type(s) of tool(s) that a common jQuery developer would use to achieve this then that's completely different.

For starters, it looks like you have found a carousel that you want to use to create the rotating effect. That's fine. You'll need to go through their API and instructions to get a grasp on how to integrate your next step:

**Drag & Drop in jQuery**

My favorite plugin for this is jQuery UI. It's a complete suite for jQuery that provides an array of different enhancements, including the 'Drag & Drop' effect you want.

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

You'll have to (once again) work with the API and instructions, and create events to control how the carousel should be affected by the Drag & Drop plugin.

**Vertical Carousel**

Some quick digging regarding the need for Vertical implementation lead me to a Stackoverflow question regarding the same exact needs.

> [JQuery Cloud Carousel that scrolls vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755844/jquery-cloud-carousel-that-scrolls-vertically)

He also discussed what changes you need to make to the script in order to account for the change in axis. That's a huge +.

You can see a working version of it below -

> http://www.inspiritandintruth.com/ (look at the right hand side)

All of this combined should get you what you want. With a bit of work and adjusting, you'll be able to get your end result.

Best of luck.